# OpenCV 3.0.0 with cmake - where are the includes/libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I compiled OpenCV 3.0.0 with TBB using Cmake and now I am unsure about where the include and library directories are (for VS 2012). I followed [these](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) instructions, however the library is not in the folder mentioned in the "set environment path" blurb (which is probably copied from an earlier version).

1. Am I right in assuming that the relevant folder is "OpenCV/Build" and "OpenCV/Source" no longer plays a role for new projects?
2. Are the needed includes and libraries in "OpenCV/Build/Install/include" and "OpenCV/Build/Install/x86/lib/vc11/lib" respectively? I added those, as well as the corresponding additional dependancies - my program

`#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"`

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
cv::Mat src = cv::imread( "C:\\pics\\test.tif",0);
cv::imshow("end",src);
    return 0;
}
```

compiles, but crashes saying:

> The program can't start because opencv_core300.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

What could be the reason?

Comment: 1) and 2) are right. Copy the required dll in the same folder where the exe is.

Comment: I would like to make property sheets like Arijit mentioned. I have OpenCV 2.4.8 running with no problems doing the same things, I just wanted to get the upgrade and TBB working as well!

Comment: Then your 2) will be ... /staticlib (not lib). I hope to remember well, I'm not at pc right now

Comment: That doesn't change the error, also it had worked without staticlib in the previous version. I tried copying the core.dll to the .exe folder, I got "The procedure entry point "?default_num_threads@task_scheduler_init@tbb@@SAHXZ" could not be located in the dynamic link library "tbb.dll"."

Comment: Previous versions are different. You probably also need to rebuild unsetting BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY

Comment: I did that, now the .../lib is missing and the /bin only contains one DLL :) this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Well you messed up something either in your cmake or your VS settings.. Good luck :D

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to specify the libraries in which the linker should look into. To do this go to the Linker ‣ Input and under the “Additional Dependencies” entry add the name of all modules which you want to use:

[image]

Add the debug library names here.Like this.
The names of the libraries are as follow:

opencv_(The Name of the module)(The version Number of the library you use)d.lib
A full list, for the latest version would contain:

```
opencv_calib3d300d.lib

opencv_contrib300d.lib

opencv_core300d.lib

opencv_features2d300d.lib

opencv_flann300d.lib

opencv_gpu300d.lib

opencv_highgui300d.lib

opencv_imgproc300d.lib

opencv_legacy300d.lib

opencv_ml300d.lib

opencv_nonfree300d.lib

opencv_objdetect300d.lib

opencv_ocl300d.lib

opencv_photo300d.lib

opencv_stitching300d.lib

opencv_superres300d.lib

opencv_ts300d.lib

opencv_video300d.lib

opencv_videostab300d.lib
```

The letter d at the end just indicates that these are the libraries required for the debug. Now click ok to save and do the same with a new property inside the Release rule section. Make sure to omit the d letters from the library names and to save the property sheets with the save icon above them.

And the release ones.
You can find your property sheets inside your projects directory. At this point it is a wise decision to back them up into some special directory, to always have them at hand in the future, whenever you create an OpenCV project. Note that for Visual Studio 2010 the file extension is props, while for 2008 this is vsprops.

And the release ones.
Next time when you make a new OpenCV project just use the “Add Existing Property Sheet...” menu entry inside the Property Manager to easily add the OpenCV build rules.

[Check this Official Instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html)

Comment: That's for static linking. The OP is dynamically linking.

Comment: That's what I had done (what I meant by "corresponding additional dependencies").

Comment: sorry I dont have enough rep to comment that's why I have to post this as an answer .  Does your path contains the folder where you have your dlls ??

Comment: Yes. However I restarted the computer and now the opencv_core.dll problem seems to have disappeared, so it was probably that. However the procedure entry point problem concerning "tbb.dll" still persists.

Comment: that's because you are pointing to the default build which don't come with tbb.dll

Comment: How would I change that then? I thought this would be done by cmake when I chose WITH_TBB .

Comment: OpenCV/Build/Install/x86/lib/vc11/lib does this contains the tbb lib ?? and the folder in the path does that contain the dll for tbb?